# Spark: Unable to find encoder for type Unit

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have dataframe like this:

```
ID  Country  Revenue
1     US       1000
2     IND      2000
3     DE       4000
```

I'm trying to convert into JSON Format and write into my local path.

**Output**:

```
[
  {
    "ID": 1,
    "Country": "US",
    "Revenue": 1000
  },
  {
    "ID": 2,
    "Country": "IND",
    "Revenue": 2000
  },......
]
```

**Code**:

```
import spark.implicits._

val DF = spark.sql("select  ID,Country,Revenue from  table")

DF.show()

case class ID(ID:int)

case class country(country:String)

case class Revenue(Revenue:Int)

case class details(ID:ID,country:country,Revenue:Revenue)

val JsonDF= DF.map(r=>{val details_1=details(r.getString(0),r.getString(1),r.getString(2))})

JsonDF.repartition(1).write.option("multiLine","true").json("C:/Desktop/output/revenue.json")
```

But I'm getting following error:

> Unable to find encoder for type Unit. An implicit Encoder[Unit] is needed to store Unit instances in a Dataset. Primitive types (Int, String, etc) and Product types (case classes) are supported by importing spark.implicits._

Where is my mistake?

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: @GaëlJ this  error   Unable to find encoder for type Unit. An implicit Encoder[Unit] is needed to store Unit instances in a Dataset. Primitive types (Int, String, etc) and Product types (case classes) are supported by importing spark.implicits._

Answer (score 1):

> Unable to find encoder for type Unit.

This means that you are storing `Unit` values in your dataset which is probably not what you want and should be a hint.

Replace the line:

```scala
val JsonDF = DF.map(r=>{val details_1=details(r.getString(0),r.getString(1),r.getString(2))})
// DataSet[Unit]
```

By:

```scala
val JsonDF = DF.map(r => details(r.getString(0),r.getString(1),r.getString(2)))
// DataSet[details]
```

In your original code you are creating a `details` instance but not returning it in the lambda.

Comment: error: ambiguous implicit values:
 both method newIntEncoder in class SQLImplicits of type => org.apache.spark.sql.Encoder[Int]
 and method newLongEncoder in class SQLImplicits of type => org.apache.spark.sql.Encoder[Long]
 match expected type org.apache.spark.sql.Encoder[U]
val JsonDF = DF.map(r => details(r.getString(0),r.getString(1),r.getString(2)))

Comment: I'm getting this  error

Comment: Do you have a custom `apply` method for `details`? And is the definition in your first post correct?

Comment: can you suggest  me on the  sample script on the given data itself  While  I'm executing the code. I'm getting  Issues.